# have a .exe run in the background and type things into that through python

Tags: python, popen

I have a program, myshell.exe, that i need to interact with through python (send commands to it and read results back).

The catch is that i can only run `myshell.exe` once (cannot enclose popen and communicate in a loop)

I have tried `popen` and `popen.communicate()` but that seems to run `myshell.exe`, send my commands and then exits the process.

```
# settin up the command
p = Popen("myshell.exe", stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)

# sending something (and getting output)
print p.communicate("run");
```

At this point, from the print output i can see that my `myshell.exe` has exited (i have a goodbye message that is printed).

Any ideas if there is any way around it ? 
Thanks.

Comment: Well, simply leave the `Popen` part outside the loop: open the communication once, interact as many times as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read in [`Popen.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) docs, it will wait until `myshell.exe` exits before returning.

Use `p.stdout` and `p.stdin` to communicate with the process instead:

```
p.stdin.write("run")
print p.stdout.read(1024)
```

`p.stdin` and `p.stdout` are regular file objects. You can read and write to them in a loop, just leave the `p = Popen(...)` part outside:

```
p = Popen("myshell.exe", stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
for i in range(3):
    p.stdin.write("run")
    print p.stdout.read(16)
p.terminate()
```

This assuming that `myshell.exe` is behaving as you expect (e.g. does not exit after first command is sent).

Comment: myshell.exe behaves OK if i run it from a windows terminal, i.e. if i type in the following sequence `run\n` it will execute run and then wait for the next command. I think communicate() sends EOF or something like that that screws up myshell.exe

Comment: You might have to add a trailing `\n` or `\r\n` after the command, e.g. `p.stdin.write("run\n")` if `myshell.exe` expects a <kbd>Return</kbd> after the command (as any interactive shell does).

Comment: I think this was it. When using `p.stdin.write("run")`, `myshell.exe` would exit. But if i send `p.stdin.write("run\r\n")` then i can keep sending things to it.